# No such column 'name' on entity 'Task'

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks

I am getting an error "No such column 'name' on entity 'Task'.  It is coming from my query but I am not querying for 'name'.  Please help.

```
public list<task> getTasks() {
list<account> myaccs = new list<account>([select id from account where ownerid =: userinfo.getuserid()]);
set<id> aid = new set<id>();
for(account a: myaccs){
    aid.add(a.id);
    }

string sortFullExp = sortfield  + ' ' + sortDirection;
    mytasks = database.query('SELECT subject, status, priority, reminderdatetime from task order by ' + sortFullExp);
    return mytasks;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that the value of 'sortfield' is 'Name'.  Use `System.debug('sortfield val = ' + sortfield);` and see what comes up.

Comment: You are correct. 'Name' was assigned to sortfield.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, could you please mark it as such?